# AES: Storing a clear part of the encrypted data for search purpose

Tags: database, encryption, aes

I encrypt sensitive text tokens with AES and store them in a database. I would like to do a partial search for these tokens and not only search exact matches.
Decrypting all tokens would be too slow so my idea would be to store the beginning of the token as clear text in an other column of the database.

A token is 90 characters and is unique for each user. I would store for example the 20 first characters.

If someone gets a copy of the database, would it be a security issue, I mean would it be easier to reconstruct the complete token having a clear part of it?

My AES encryption settings are :

- AES-128 with a 32 bytes encryption key.
- encryption mode is CBC.
- IV are unique for each token.

Comment: I know too little to post an answer, but I think you theoretically, for the general case, run the additional risk of known-plaintext attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) - however, at least as the wikipedia article states, AES is currently not susceptible to such attacks. Don't know of any detailed analysis on this, though. Anyhow, isn't it a bit of a security problem already that part of this sensitive data is available in plaintext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a hash for each value (or the first part of each value if they are long), such as the first 20 bytes of PBKDF2 with 10,000 iterations, and store that as a separate field/column. To check a value, perform the same operation and check it against the new field. The value in the new field is not reversable and the comparison operations are cheap (straight binary comparison).